# Unable to use Chrome Web Store Publish API due to force 2-Factor verification

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, chrome-web-store

Until recently I have been releasing Chrome Extension using [Chrome Web Store Publish API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/). (Automated release process)

```
   const response = execSync(`\
      curl -X PUT -F 'data=@${process.env.ZIP_FILE}' https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/${extensionId} \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer ${accessToken}" \
      -H "x-goog-api-version: 2" 
  `);
```

Due to the latest set of [policy changes](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/policy-update-2sv/) to limit extensions abuse and improve the security of the Chrome Web Store, this includes requiring 2FA for Chrome Web Store developers, I am not able to publish chrome ext anymore.

Is there any way how to release chrome ext using **Chrome Web Store Publish API** without requiring 2-Factor verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but to clarify the **developer account** just needs to have two factor authentication enabled. You will still be able to publish extensions through an automated script, but 2FA needs to be setup first.